# How to supplement boost::exception with a proper what() function

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I like [boost::exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) quite a bit, but I'm quite bothered it does not provide a proper [what](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/what/)() function out of the box. Now don't get confused, it does have a nice [boost::diagnostic_information](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/exception/doc/diagnostic_information.html) that contains all the information I would like to see in my hypothetic `what()` function but since `boost::exception` does not inherit from `std::exception` the `what()` function I get if I multiple inherit (as suggested from the tutorial, see line below) is the default useless `what()` from the `std::exception` base that explains nothing about the exception.

```
struct my_exception: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception { };
```

Now obviously I tried to override `what()` and make it return `boost::diagnostic_information` but somehow it just does not work, so I'm a bit puzzled. That might be because it would loop but I'm not quite sure.

PS: The reason I want to implement `what()` right is that it is shown by default by a lot of tools if your program dies from them (e.g. the gnu compiler will show a nice fatal error, and display what(), boost unit tests tools etc.).

[Here's a link to the test code below](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=12651c1c97fdd3439bbab2d136f6645b-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

```
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

struct my_exception: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception {};

struct my_exception2: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception {
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return "WHAT";
    }
};

struct my_exception3: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception {
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return boost::diagnostic_information(this).c_str();
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_exception());
    } catch (const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; 
        //This is useless ___ std::exception
    }

    try {
        BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_exception());
    } catch (const boost::exception& e){
        std::cout << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << std::endl; 
        //This is what I'd like to see ___ main.cpp(39): Throw in function int main() ___ Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl ___ std::exception::what: std::exception
    }

    try {
        BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_exception2());
    } catch (const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; 
        //Overriding what usually works ___ WHAT
    }

    try {
        BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_exception3());
    } catch (const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; 
        //But somehow here it does not work ___ Unknown exception.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the winner is...

```
namespace boost {
    char const * diagnostic_information_what( boost::exception const & e ) throw();
}
```

Comment: If this answer solves the question, it would be good for you to accept it :3.

Answer (score 3):

First, `boost::diagnostic_information` takes an exception by (const) reference, and `this` is a pointer:

```
    return boost::diagnostic_information(*this).c_str();
                                         ^-- here
```

Second, once you've fixed that, as you've correctly anticipated this results in infinite recursion as `boost::diagnostic_information` calls `std::exception::what()`.  It is possible to work around this with a guard member or something similar:

```
struct my_exception3: std::exception, boost::exception {
    mutable bool in_what = false;
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        struct g { bool &b; ~g() { b = false; } } guard{in_what};
        return in_what ? "WHAT" : (in_what = true, boost::diagnostic_information(*this).c_str());
    }
};
```

Finally, you're using `c_str` from a destructed temporary `string`.  I'll leave the solution to that problem as an exercise.

Comment: [Here's my tentative answer to your exercize](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6d5b9907dd7c4f5a728e0dd3d1ab87b8-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94). I'm a bit annoyed that it freezes the content of what() though.

Comment: damn, i found the real answer, below. Sorry about the not-so-smart question